# Open a Modal Using an Option from a Dropdown - Angular 2 + ngx

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli, twitter-bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

Using ngx-bootstrap (4) with Angular 2/CLI.

Trying to use a dropdown list to select which modal to open.
The modal currently works fine if I just have a button for each modal (not a dropdown), but the requirements call for a dropdown.

I tried something like

```
<select class="detailsOption" (change)="openModal($event.target.value)">
   <option value="">Select Option</option>
   <option value={{modal1}} >Option 1</option>
   <option value={{modal2}}>Option 2</option>
</select>

<ng-template #modal1>
</ng-template

<ng-template #modal2>
</ng-template

openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
}
```

Obviously this example wouldn't work. But I was trying to find a way have the option values hold the template, and then when selected, would pass the template into openModal and then open the modal.

I did find this guys question but it had no answers and also he was using click events in a drop down which don't really trigger I believe.
[ngx-bootstrap calling a modal from a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879021/ngx-bootstrap-calling-a-modal-from-a-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by opening the modal in the `(change)` event of the `select`

```
<select class="detailsOption" (change)="openModal($event.target.value)">
     <option value="">Select Option</option>
     <option value="modal1" >Option 1</option>
     <option value="modal2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<!-- Option 1 -->
<common-modal  #childModalOption1 [title]="'Option1 modal'"> 
    <div class="modal-body">Option 1 selected Modal </div>
</common-modal> 

<!-- Option 2 -->
<common-modal  #childModalOption2 [title]="'Option 2modal'"> 
    <div class="modal-body">Option 2 selected Modal </div>
</common-modal>
```

You should be having multiple references of the `modal-component` by decorating them with `@ViewChild` decorator

```
@ViewChild('childModalOption1') childModalOption1 :CommonModalComponent;
@ViewChild('childModalOption2') childModalOption2 :CommonModalComponent;
```

Your `openModal` method should be as

```
openModal(event){
    if(event==='modal1'){
      this.childModalOption1.show()
      console.log(event)  
    } else if(event==='modal2'){
      this.childModalOption2.show()
    }
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xh8VLnfCLxMYmnR5EvJY?p=preview)**

Comment: So basically in the component file you have a references to the modal itself, and then you call show on that reference? Is that understanding mostly correct?

Comment: @canpan14 yes your understanding is correct. Reason for having a `common-modal-component` is to remove the redundant bootstrap code

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the assistance, I'll mark this correct once I can test it out (left the office sadly).

Comment: @canpan14 ok. take your time. let me know if you need more help

Comment: That worked, I did have to do this.modalService.show(childModalOption1) though.

Comment: Happy helping you. :)