# How to pop up a modal from click in dropdown list option

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu

Good day developers , im working in this app with angular , and now im trying to  once one  of the options 
get clicked , to show a modal tag .
Basically what i did was create a paralell template equal to the item selected on the dropdown , and over this template using the a tag i set all the logic to show the modal, but guess isn't user friendly cause of couple extra clicks.Trying to set the a tag inside the options also wasn't viable cause the my dropdown didn't work.Here a mock about what i did:

```
HTML tag

      <select [hidden]="!state" name="optionsInc" required [(ngModel)]="optionsInc" (change)="subItemSelected($event)">
        <option value="select" [ngValue]="null" [disabled]="true">Select Income</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of allKeysIncomings" label="{{item}}" value="{{item}}"></option>
      </select>====>DROPDOWN LIST LOGIC


    <p [hidden]="!state"> <a *ngIf="incomeSelected"
      href="#"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
      data-toggle="modal"
      data-target="#editItem"
    >{{incomeSelected}}</a>
    </p>====>PARALELL REFERENCE TO POP THE MODAL UP

    <div class="modal fade" id='editItem'>======>MODAL 
      SOME TAGS AND CODE
    </div>
```

then on my component i did this :

```
imports...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-sheet-balance',
  templateUrl: './user-sheet-balance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-sheet-balance.component.css'],
})
export class UserSheetBalanceComponent implements OnInit {

allKeysIncomings: any;==>ITERABLE
incomeSelected: string;

constructor(some code) {}

ngOnInit(): void {some code}

  async subItemSelected(event) {
    SOME CODE
      return (
        await (this.incomeSelected = event.target.value),
     );
  }
```

All this process does the task on activate the modal once i click the tag a, but instead of creating that paralell reference to the dropdown, im wondering if is possible to do it straight from the dropdown in fact.
I have been watching some similar issues on the comunity like 
:[Open a Modal Using an Option from a Dropdown - Angular 2 + ngx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349426/open-a-modal-using-an-option-from-a-dropdown-angular-2-ngx)
but doesn't work on my code specifications.
Any updated idea about this ?.Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `Component` with dialog layout in `ModalComponent` it should work as follow

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
    import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class TestDialogService {

      dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent, any>;

      constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

      open() {
        if(this.dialogRef) {
          this.dialogRef.close();
        }
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
          panelClass: 'app-dialog'
        });
      }

      close() {
        if(this.dialogRef) {
          this.dialogRef.close();
        }
      }
    }

    // html
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Favorite car</mat-label>
      <select name="optionsInc"
        matNativeControl 
        [(ngModel)]="optionsInc" 
        (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()">

        <option value="select" [value]="null" [disabled]="true">Select Income</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of allKeysIncomings" [label]="item.viewValue" 
          [value]="item.value"></option>
      </select>
    </mat-form-field>

    // ts
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      state = false;
      optionsInc = null;
      allKeysIncomings = [
        {value: 'volvo', viewValue: 'Volvo'},
        {value: 'saab', viewValue: 'Saab'},
        {value: 'mercedes', viewValue: 'Mercedes'}
      ];

      constructor(
        public testDialogService: TestDialogService) {
      }

      onModelChange() {
        this.testDialogService.open();
      }
    }
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-service?file=src/app/test-dialog.service.ts)

Comment: sorry for constantly being asking you  but im new in this of angular , and doing it by myself  is twicely hard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019241/updating-a-field-inside-a-firebase-firestore-doc-without-hand-write-the-field-ke  .Sorry for constantly ask to you simple questions

Comment: sorry again radik...Again have another doubdt..really sorry !!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064163/data-persistence-on-angular-with-firestore-after-page-reload